# How are duplicate class names resolved in data classes?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

While working with data classes I declared duplicate data class and realized that on creating objects with them, the code worked perfectly fine, as long as I was using the format mentioned on the most recent line from the bottom.

Is duplicate naming really allowed? Can I do some kind of overloading with duplicate data class names? What about inheriting from the data class of the same name?

Comment: No it's not overloading. It's redefinition and the last one will be used in the program. In fact you can redefine every function (even built-in functions of python) every where you want.

Comment: This has nothing to do with dataclasses. A `class` statement is just a fancy assignment statement; it processes the body, does some stuff to orchestrate a call to the metaclass, then binds the resulting object to the name following the `class` keyword. If you use the same class name twice, you simply overwrite the old value with the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you can reassign a new value to a name with an assignment statement

```
x = 1
x = 2
assert x == 2
```

you can assign a new class object to a name with a `class` statement.

```
class X:
    pass

old_X = X

class X:
    pass

assert old_X is not X
```

A `class` statement itself, is a declarative syntax that does three things:

1. Evaluates its body to define some names
2. Pass a dict constructed from the names and their values to the metaclass to create a new class
3. Assigns the return value of the call to the metaclass to the name given by the `class` statement.

You are just observing the 3rd step.